# Monospace Margin between elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, mono, styles, margin, space

I want the space between the child elements in, for example, StackPanel be the same. When using the same Margin for child elements, gap between neighbors doubles. I'm using a little trick to solve this, but it seems to me there is more elegant solution. May be you have one?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4,4,0,4" />
    ...
</Style>
<Style x:Key="LastMyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MyButton}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
</Style>
```

I'm using MyButtonStyle for all buttons except the last one, which use LastMyButtonStyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the StackPanel in another container, i.e. a Border, and set its Margin to the same value as those of the Buttons:

```
<Border>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
        <Button Margin="2" Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button Margin="2" Content="Button 2"/>
        <Button Margin="2" Content="Button 3"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Of course, It's a good solution. But again it's using 2 styles. and I'm searching for something more. I'm interesting how we can do the same effect in one style. Maybe I want too much))) It's just a research. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Sure, but you would only have one Style for Button, and one for StackPanel, which means you can make them default Styles. You would hence not need to apply them explicitly to every element.

Comment: Yes, default style for type looks good. For now I'll choose this approach. Thanks a lot!